# Ukrainian "і" replaced with latin on compilation

Tags: pdftex, babel, ukrainian

Using `pdflatex` and `babel` on compilation Ukrainian letter `і` (U+0456) is replaced with Latin `i` (U+0069).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ukrainian]{babel}

\begin{document}
  Привіт
\end{document}
```

Results in PDF file:

```
Привiт
```

Where `i` is Latin. There is no difference in the appearance, but it creates issues with plagiarism check. I need Ukrainian `і` to stay as it is in PDF.

Comment: Not with the T2A encoding, sorry. Because of space constraints the Cyrillic “i” is taken from the Latin part of the encoding. You get a real Cyrillic "i" if you use XeLaTeX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can map the i to the cyrillic і. But then you map all of them, that means that i in a text using T1-encoding will copy as cyrillic i too. There is imho no easy fix, the fonts and encodings were created at a time where unicode conformance and copy&paste wasn't something that really mattered.

You should use an unicode engine like lualatex or xelatex for a real solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ukrainian]{babel}
\input{glyphtounicode}
\pdfgentounicode=1
\pdfglyphtounicode{i}{0456}
\begin{document}
  Привіт
  
  \fontencoding{T1}\selectfont iii
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'll consider switching to xelatex, but it requires some extra configuration work, so a quick workaround could help. But your solution still produces Latin `i` for me.

Comment: when I copy & paste (tested with sumatra and adobe reader on windows) I get U+0456. If your pdfviewer doesn't do this, it ignores the tounicode value. Then there is nothing you can do.

Comment: Tried Document Viewer, Zathura and converted PDF to Google Doc, and still got Latin char, which makes me think something goes wrong during compilation. I'll try xelatex.

Comment: Funny, rendering with xelatex creates PDF with only Latin `i` visible without other Cyrillic letters. Probably my `texl-live` or system setup is messed up.

Comment: You can't use the document as is with xelatex,  you must adapt the font setup.

Comment: Xelatex works as expected now, thanks.